# Add/Merge/Melt only specific columns and give out one unique row

Tags: r, dplyr, data-analysis

I am trying to transform a dataset that has multiple product sales on a date. At the end I want to keep only unique columns with the sum of the product sales per day.

My MRE:

```
df <- data.frame(created = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-03"), "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "GMT"),
                soldUnits = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
Weekday = c("Mo","Mo","Tu","Tu","Th","Th"),
Sunshinehours = c(7.8,7.8,6.0,6.0,8.0,8.0))
```

Which looks like this:

```
       Date   soldUnits Weekday Sunshinehours
     2020-01-01   1       Mo      7.8
     2020-01-01   1       Mo      7.8
     2020-01-02   1       Tu      6.0
     2020-01-02   1       Tu      6.0
     2020-01-03   1       We      8.0
     2020-01-03   1       We      8.0
```

And should look like this after transforming:

```
       Date   soldUnits Weekday Sunshinehours
     2020-01-01   2      Mo      7.8
     2020-01-02   2      Tu      6.0
     2020-01-03   2      We      8.0
```

I tried `aggregate()` and `group_by` but without success because my data was dropped.

Is there anyone who has an idea, how i can transform and clean up my dataset according to the specifications i mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can work:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(created) %>% 
  count(Weekday, Sunshinehours, wt = soldUnits,name = "soldUnits")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#> # Groups:   created [3]
#>   created    Weekday Sunshinehours soldUnits
#>   <date>     <chr>           <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 2020-01-01 Mo                7.8         2
#> 2 2020-01-02 Tu                6           2
#> 3 2020-01-03 Th                8           2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Applying different functions to different columns (or set of columns) can be done with `collap`

```
library(collapse)
collap(df, ~ created + Weekday, 
    custom = list(fmean = "Sunshinehours", fsum = "soldUnits"))
     created soldUnits Weekday Sunshinehours
1 2020-01-01         2      Mo           7.8
2 2020-01-02         2      Tu           6.0
3 2020-01-03         2      Th           8.0
```

Comment: This is a great solution as well!
Collapse seems to be a great library, thank you for mentioning it.

Answer (score 2):

Another `dplyr` approach:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(created, Weekday, Sunshinehours) %>% 
  summarise(soldUnits = sum(soldUnits))
```

```
  created    Weekday Sunshinehours soldUnits
  <date>     <chr>           <dbl>     <dbl>
1 2020-01-01 Mo                7.8         2
2 2020-01-02 Tu                6           2
3 2020-01-03 Th                8           2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `base` and `dplyr` R

```
df1 = aggregate(df["Sunshinehours"], by=df["created"], mean)
df2 = aggregate(df["soldUnits"], by=df["created"], sum)
df3 = inner_join(df1, df2)

#converting `Weekday` to factors 
df$Weekday = as.factor(df$Weekday)
df3$Weekday = levels(df$Weekday)
     created Sunshinehours soldUnits Weekday
1 2020-01-01           7.8         2      Mo
2 2020-01-02           6.0         2      Th
3 2020-01-03           8.0         2      Tu
```

Comment: `innrer_join` is from `dplyr`.

Comment: It is only one dataframe that I try to transform and clean up, why are you using 3 dataframes in your solution?